# File google-services.json is missing?

Tags: android, json, firebase

i have tried to download the json file on firebase.i have tried the procedure given by firebase console and i am still facing a challenge.

File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
Searched Location:
C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Stam\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Stam\app\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Stam\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Stam\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Stam\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Stam\app\google-services.json

Comment: Did you copy and paste it into the right path ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the `google-services.json` file from Firebase Console and put in under `C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\Stam\app\` folder.